# Adding data to wxlistbox

Tags: wxpython

How do I add data to an item in a wxlistbox control?

Lets say I have a record of items, I wanna add their id from the database as the data of the item:

```
Label   Data
--------------
Shoes   1
Watch   2
Bags    3
```

Comment: have you tried this: wxNode<T> * WxList::Append(long key, T *object)

Comment: I ended up subclassing wxlistbox.

Answer (score 0):

You can either add the items when you create the list, or append them later.  Items are added as a list of strings.  The following example shows items being added each way.

```
import wx

app = wx.App()
frame = wx.Frame(parent=None, id=-1, title = "Test List Box",size=(200,300) )
panel = wx.Panel(frame)

lb = wx.ListBox(panel,-1,(20,20),(100,200),["Shoes  1","Watch  2"])
lb.InsertItems(["Bags    3","Hats     5"],2)

frame.Show()
app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: But I want 1, 2 and 3 to be data of the items. Not part of the label. So the only thing that will show up are Shoes, Watch and Bag.

Answer (score 0):

Use wx.listctrl instead. That permits multiple columns.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote something up about this:

http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/12/16/wxpython-storing-object-in-combobox-or-listbox-widgets/

That should get you going.